# Multiple actions getting triggered ngrx8

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx, angular8

The loginsuccess gets trigerred twice on dispatching the login action, the redux flow is working as expected i'm unable to trace why the login success gets trigerred twice. I have pasted the complete code structure and I need some help in fixing this, thanks.

```
auth.actions.ts
export class Login implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.Login;
  constructor(public payload: {login: ILogin}) {}
}

export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.LoginSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: ILogin) {}
}

export class LoginFailure implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.LoginFailure;
  constructor(public payload: { err: any }) {}
}
```

auth.effects.ts

```
@Effect()
  logAdd = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    switchMap((action: any) =>
    this.authService.loginRequest(action.payload.login)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => new LoginSuccess(res)),
      catchError(err => of(new LoginFailure({err})))
    ))),{dispatch: false}
  )
}
```

auth.reducer.ts

```
export interface AuthState {
  login: ILogin
}

export interface AuthPartialState {
  readonly [AUTH_FEATURE_KEY]: AuthState;
}

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  login: null
};

export function authReducer(
  state: AuthState = initialState,
  action: AuthAction
): AuthState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.LoginSuccess: {
      state = {
        ...state,
       login: action.payload
      };
      break;
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

From login.component.ts

```
onSubmit(){
    this.store.dispatch(new loginRequest.Login({
      login: {
        username: this.login.value.username,
        password: this.login.value.password
      }
    }))
  }
```

I have attached the screenshot from redux devtools on how it is trigerred.
[image: Redux DevTools]

As shown the picture, both login success comes up with username and password. I Updated effects according to ngrx 8 but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you mix up between ngrx v7 and v8 syntax, you should used one syntax only to avoid unexpected behavior. Maybe you will need to return like this

```
@Effect()
  logAdd = createEffect(() => this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    switchMap((action: any) =>
    return this.authService.loginRequest(action.payload.login)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => new LoginSuccess(res)),
      catchError(err => of(new LoginFailure({err})))
    )))
  )
}
```

Example:

```
getPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.LoadPosts),
      switchMap(_ => {
        return this.postService
          .getPosts()
          .pipe(
            map(
              (posts: IPost[]) => PostActions.LoadPostsSuccess({ posts }),
              catchError(errors => of(PostActions.LoadPostsFail(errors)))
            )
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The effect is registered twice in your example, once with the `@Effect()` decorator and the second time with the `createEffect` factory function.

If you remove the `@Effect()`, it will only dispatch once.

You can make use of the ngrx linting rules I've been creating to prevent this - https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-tslint-rules

Comment: Thanks, but still facing the same issue, it may be due to latest version ngrx 8. I think I need to rewrite actions, reducers nd effects accordring to version 8.

Comment: You should not have to, if you have a reproduction I'm happy to take a look

Comment: Thanks Tim, that was a mistake from my side. I had forRoot in Auth.module. Changed it to forFeature and added forRoot in App.module and it worked fine. Used your blog as reference.